# How to read all the data of Common Crawl from AWS with Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, common-crawl

I'm totally new to Hadoop and MapReduce programming, and I'm trying to write my first MapReduce program with the data of Common Crawl.

I would like to read all the data of April 2015 from AWS.
For example, if I want download all the data of April 2015 in command line, I do:

> s3cmd get s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2015-18/segments/1429246633512.41/wat/*.warc.wat.gz

This command line work, but I don't want download all the data of April 2015, I just want read all the "warc.wat.gz" files (in order to analyze the data).

I try to create my job, that look like this:

```
public class FirstJob extends Configured implements Tool {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FirstJob.class);

    /**
     * Main entry point that uses the {@link ToolRunner} class to run the Hadoop
     * job.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new FirstJob(), args);
        System.out.println("done !!");
        System.exit(res);
    }

    /**
     * Builds and runs the Hadoop job.
     * 
     * @return 0 if the Hadoop job completes successfully and 1 otherwise.
     */
    public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        //
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(FirstJob.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        //String inputPath = "data/*.warc.wat.gz";
        String inputPath = "s3n://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2015-18/segments/1429246633512.41/wat/*.warc.wat.gz";
        LOG.info("Input path: " + inputPath);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputPath));

        String outputPath = "/tmp/cc-firstjob/";
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.newInstance(conf);
        if (fs.exists(new Path(outputPath))) {
            fs.delete(new Path(outputPath), true);
        }
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));

        job.setInputFormatClass(WARCFileInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(FirstJobUrlTypeMap.ServerMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class);

        if (job.waitForCompletion(true)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

But I've got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).

How I can resolve my problem ?
thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
In the code, change:

```
 Configuration conf = getConf();
 //
 Job job = new Job(conf);
```

to

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "your_key");
conf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "your_key");
Job job = new Job(conf);
```